# Python 3- Ayuda con elif en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi pregunta es sencilla, porque cuando escribo:

por ejemplo:

```
a=int(0)
b=int(0)
c=int(0)
if a==0:
    print(2+2==0)
elif b==0:
    print(2+1==3)
elif c==0:
    print(2+1==1)
```

la salida en la shell es solo el primer false

pero si hago lo mismo con solos if , me imprime false, true y después false. Porque no sucede lo mismo con el elif, Mi profesor de programación me dijo que el elif preguntaba de igual manera la condicion

```
a==int(0)
b=int(0)
c=int(0)
if a==0:
   print(2+2==0)
if b==0:
   print(2+1=3)
if c==0:
   print(2+1==1)
```

Comment: No hace falta que declares el tipo de variable cuando la creas. Python se da cuenta por si solo. Ademas, int() se usa para pasar variables de tipo float (1.45) a integrer (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primer ejemplo**

La ejecución del mismo se detiene en el primer `if()` pues dicha condición es `TRUE` y el resto de evaluaciones se descartan:

Recordando que:

- `if` Evalúa de manera lógica si una condición se cumple o no, en caso de cumplirse ejecuta una acción y en caso contrario pasa a la siguiente evaluación que dentro de tu código serían los `elif`

**Estructura**

```
if(condición es verdadera){
  //se ejecutan acciones
}else if(condición es verdadera){
  //se ejecutan otras acciones si el primer `if` fue falso
}else{
  //si ninguna de las comparaciones anteriores resulto cierta, entonces se generan acciones por defecto
}
```

**Segundo ejemplo**

La ejecución del mismo avanza e imprime los resultados de los 3 condicionales `if` pues cada una se considera aislada del resto.

Recordando que:

- `if` evalúa una condición y de resultar cierta ejecuta una serie de acciones y en caso contrario pasaría a evaluar otra condición, que en este caso no existe pues son 3 `if` por separado.

**Ejemplo 1**

En el siguiente ejemplo, evaluamos la igualdad de cada variable por separado y dependiendo de si cada una de las 3 condiciones regresan `TRUE` entonces se imprime un resultado:

```
a=int(10)
b=int(20)
c=int(30)
if a==10:
    print(10)
if b==20:
    print(20)
if c==30:
    print(30)
```

Resultado

```
10
20
30
```

Ahora si modificamos un poco dicho ejemplo y la variable `a` la igualamos a `11` entonces la primer condición ya no se cumple, pero no existe una estructura de control para evaluar de nuevo dicha variable y retornar en consecuencia una serie de acciones

```
a=int(11)
b=int(20)
c=int(30)
if a==10:
    print(10)
if b==20:
    print(20)
if c==30:
    print(30)
```

Resultado:

```
20
30
```

**Tercer ejemplo**

Ahora incluso con el puro uso de condicionales `if` pudiéramos evaluar el valor de una sola variable y en consecuencia retornar un valor específico

```
a=int(20)

if a==10:
    print("Estoy en el primer if")
if a==20:
    print("Estoy en el segundo if")
if a==30:
    print("Estoy en el tercer if")
```

Resultado:

> Estoy en el segundo `if`

Comment: Gracias , que gran respuesta.Eres Dios.